# Change the text value of paragraph and span elements via DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to get similar output to this [image]

However, when the button is clicked the event listener cannot change the quote and the author at the same time. I had to comment out one to see the other.
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="quote-box">
    <p class="quote-text">The love of money is the root of all evils.
        The love of money is the root of all evils.
        <span class="author">Author</span>
    </p>
    <div class="bottom-right">
        <button class="quote-btn">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
*{
    background-color: #BBB23E
}

.quote-box{
    background-color:#3E95BB;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
}

.quote-box{
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.quote-text{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}

.author{
    border:2px red solid;
}

.bottom-right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0.5rem;
    bottom:0.5rem; 
}
```

Here is the Javascript

```
function pickFromArray(choices) {
    return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
}
let btnEl = document.querySelector("button");
let quoteEl = document.querySelector("p");
let authorEl = document.querySelector("span");
console.log(quoteEl);
btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let radnomQuote = pickFromArray(quotes);
    console.log(radnomQuote);
    quoteEl.textContent = radnomQuote.quote;
    authorEl.innerHTML = radnomQuote.author;
    console.log(authorEl.textContent);
})
```

And here is the quotes array

```
const quotes = [
    {
        quote: "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.",
        author: "Kevin Kruse",
    },
    {
        quote: "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve.",
        author: "Napoleon Hill",
    },
    {
        quote: "Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value.",
        author: "Albert Einstein",
    }
]
```

I have tried innerHTML too but nothing seems to work. But when I take the span out of the p tag and apply position absolute to the author class the author appears outside of the white background which is not what I would like to see. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you set the paragraph's innerHTML you remove the span. Try this one.

```js
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.",
    author: "Kevin Kruse",
  },
  {
    quote: "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve.",
    author: "Napoleon Hill",
  },
  {
    quote: "Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value.",
    author: "Albert Einstein",
  }]
  
function pickFromArray(choices) {
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
}

function createAuthor(value) {
  const author = document.createElement('span');
  author.innerHTML = value;
  return author;
}

let btnEl = document.querySelector("button");
let quoteEl = document.querySelector("p");

console.log(quoteEl);
btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let radnomQuote = pickFromArray(quotes);
  console.log(radnomQuote);
  quoteEl.textContent = radnomQuote.quote;
  const authorSpan = createAuthor(radnomQuote.author);
  quoteEl.appendChild(authorSpan);
})
```

```css
*{
    background-color: #BBB23E
}
.quote-box{
    background-color:#3E95BB;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;

}
.quote-box{
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.quote-text{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.author{
  
    border:2px red solid;
}
.bottom-right{
    position:absolute;
   right:0.5rem;
   bottom:0.5rem; 
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
          
        <p class="quote-text">The love of money is the root of all evils.
          The love of money is the root of all evils.
        <span class="author">Author</span>
        </p>
          <div class="bottom-right">
        <button class="quote-btn">CLICK ME</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ Pablo Darde thank you so much. The helper function is a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is setting `quoteEl.textContent` effectively removes the author span. Instead, set `quoteEl.firstChild.textContent`

```js
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.",
    author: "Kevin Kruse",
  },
  {
    quote: "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve.",
    author: "Napoleon Hill",
  },
  {
    quote: "Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value.",
    author: "Albert Einstein",
  }]
  
function pickFromArray(choices) {
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
}

let btnEl = document.querySelector("button");
let quoteEl = document.querySelector("p");
let authorEl = document.querySelector("span");
//console.log(quoteEl);

btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let radnomQuote = pickFromArray(quotes);
//  console.log(radnomQuote);
  quoteEl.firstChild.textContent = radnomQuote.quote;
  authorEl.innerHTML = radnomQuote.author;
//  console.log(authorEl.textContent);
})
```

```css
*{
    background-color: #BBB23E
}
.quote-box{
    background-color:#3E95BB;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;

}
.quote-box{
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.quote-text{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.author{
    border:2px red solid;
}
.bottom-right{
    position:absolute;
   right:0.5rem;
   bottom:0.5rem; 
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
          
        <p class="quote-text">The love of money is the root of all evils.
          The love of money is the root of all evils.
        <span class="author">Author</span>
        </p>
          <div class="bottom-right">
        <button class="quote-btn">CLICK ME</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).